# If $g:X \to [0,\infty)$ is defined by $g(x)=d(x,f(x))$, prove that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $f:X \to X$ be a function on a compact metric space $(X,d)$ such that

$d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ for all $x\neq y$

a) If $g:X \to [0,\infty)$ is defined by $g(x)=d(x,f(x))$, prove that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

b) Prove that $f$ has a unique fixed point in X.

My attempt:

a) We must show that $g$ is uniformly continuous on X.
Let $g:X \to [0,\infty)$ be defined by $g(x)=d(x,f(x))$

Choose $\epsilon>0$. Set $\delta=\epsilon/2$.

Then, let $\delta>0$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$,
we have

|$g(x)-g(y)$| = $d(x,f(x))-d(y,f(y))$

=$||x-f(x)|-|y-f(y)||$

$=||x-f(x)+f(x)|-|y-f(y)+f(y)||$

$\leq|(|x-f(x)|+f(x))-(|y-f(y)|+f(y))|$

However, I'm stuck in this step,

what I need to do is to somehow make the following inequality

|$g(x)-g(y)| < d(x,y) + d(f(x),f(y))$

which would lead to

$< 2d(x,y) < 2\delta \leq 2(\epsilon/2) \leq \epsilon$

However, I can't seem to get pass the above step. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For (b) We must show that there exists a unique fixed point $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = x$, i.e. such that $g(x) = 0$

I know that by compactness there exists a $z \in X$ such that $inf_{x \in X} g(x) = g(z)$ by Theorem. So existence of this x is given by compactness and continuity, however, I'm stuck following this. I know I still need to prove uniqueness as well, but does the previous statement serve as a proof for existence?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $f$ is continuous and so does $d$. So $g$ is continuous on compact space $X$, which means that $g$ is uniformly  continuous.

Comment: If $g(z)=d(z,f(z))>0$, then $g(f(z))=d(f(z),f^2(z))<d(z,f(z))=g(z)$. Then $g(z)$ is not the minimum value, since $g(f(z))<g(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f$ is continuous as $$x_n\rightarrow x\implies d(x_n,x)\rightarrow 0\implies d(f(x_n),f(x))\rightarrow 0$$ as $d(f(x),f(y))≤d(x,y)$. Next note that $d:X×X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is continuous , therefore $$x_n\rightarrow x\implies (x_n,f(x_n))\rightarrow (x,f(x))\implies  d(x_n,f(x_n))\rightarrow d(x,f(x)).$$ Hence $g$ is continuous. Compactness of $X$ implies $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Let if possible $$g(a)=inf_{x\in X} d(x,f(x))>0\implies d(a,f(a))>0\implies a\not =f(a)\implies d(f(a),f(f(a)))<d(a,f(a))\implies g(f(a))<g(a)=inf_{x\in X} g(x),$$ contradiction. Hence $g(a)=0\implies$ $f$ has a fixed point, namely $a$.

Let $b$ be a fixed point of $f$ and $a\not= b$ , then $d(a,b)>0$ and $$d(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b)<d(a,b),$$ contradiction. So $f$ has unique fixed point.

**Another way of proving uniform continuity of $g$ is given below :--**

$$g(x)=d(x,f(x))≤d(x,y)+d(y,f(y))+d(f(y),f(x))≤2d(x,y)+g(y)\implies |g(x)-g(y)|≤2d(x,y),\forall x,y\in X.$$ The last inequality follows from interchanging the role of $x,y$ and $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

Comment: Thank you SOO MUCH!! This was a huge help!